# Import of CSV data into PostgreSQL using psycopg3 results in psycopg.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg3

I have a CSV file `my_table.csv` that looks like the following:

```
"dt_start","my_int_value","my_double_value","dt_version"
"2022-01-02 00:00:00",2,2.2,"2022-01-02 00:00:00"
"2022-01-03 00:00:00",3,3.3,"2022-01-03 00:00:00"
```

Now I simply want to import this file into a table `my_table` of my PostgreSQL database from Python using the [instructions](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html) from the `psycopg3` package (using `psycopg==3.1.3` and `psycopg-binary==3.1.3`).

My code looks as follows:

```
import os
import psycopg


table_name = "my_table"

conn = psycopg.connect(
    dbname="MY_DB",
    user="MY_USER",
    password="MY_PW",
    host="MY_HOST",
    port="MY_PORT",
)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:

        # create table
        cur.execute(
            f"""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
                dt_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                my_int_value INT NOT NULL,
                my_double_value DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
                dt_version TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                PRIMARY KEY(dt_start, my_int_value, my_double_value, dt_version)
            )
            """
        )

        # clear table
        cur.execute(f"TRUNCATE {table_name}")
        conn.commit()

        # insert one row
        cur.execute(
            f"""INSERT INTO {table_name}"""
            + f""" (dt_start, my_int_value, my_double_value, dt_version)"""
            + f""" VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""",
            ("2022-01-01 00:00:00", 1, 1.1, "2022-01-01 00:00:00"),
        )
        conn.commit()

        # fetch it
        cur.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM {table_name}""")
        print(cur.fetchall())

        # this breaks with "psycopg.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat"
        with open(f"""{table_name}.csv""", "r") as f:
            with cur.copy(f"COPY {table_name} FROM STDIN") as copy:
                while data := f.read(100):
                    copy.write(data)
        conn.commit()
```

The first steps with some sample data work perfectly, but the CSV import breaks with an error such as:

```
psycopg.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid syntax for type timestamp without time zone: »"dt_start","my_int_value","my_double_value","dt_version"«    
CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, Row 1, Column dt_start: »"dt_start","my_int_value","my_double_value","dt_version"«
```

Meanwhile, I have also tried different import variants from the docs and different datetime formats, but all result in the same error.

Any hints on how to fix this problem?

Comment: 1) **Do not** use `f` strings to build dynamic SQL Use the `psycopg` [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/sql.html) module. 2) The issue is that `"COPY {table_name} FROM STDIN` assumes the CSV is in text format as defined here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) and in that case separator is the tab character, `\t` not `,`. Which is why you get `»"dt_start","my_int_value","my_double_value","dt_version"«` as being the value for column `dt_start`. Also you are reading the header as the first data line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally missed the header :-) And good to know that there are better ways to build the queries which is why I chose your answer.

Comment: I think your comment would create additional value in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table import_test(dt_start timestamp, my_int_value integer, my_double_value float, dt_version timestamp);

cat import_test.csv
"dt_start","my_int_value","my_double_value","dt_version"
"2022-01-02 00:00:00",2,2.2,"2022-01-02 00:00:00"
"2022-01-03 00:00:00",3,3.3,"2022-01-03 00:00:00"

import psycopg
from psycopg import sql

con = psycopg.connect("dbname=test user=postgres host=localhost port=5432")

with open('import_test.csv') as f:
    with cur.copy(sql.SQL('COPY {} FROM STDIN WITH(FORMAT CSV, HEADER)').format(sql.Identifier('import_test'))) as copy:
                while data := f.read(100):
                    copy.write(data)

con.commit()

select * from import_test ;
      dt_start       | my_int_value | my_double_value |     dt_version      
---------------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------------
 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |            2 |             2.2 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00
 2022-01-03 00:00:00 |            3 |             3.3 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Super helpful. Couldn't find this anywhere in the docs. Thanks. 

Comment: Actually it was almost a direct lift from here [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html#copy).

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I wasn't able to put it all together until I read your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The file contains a header, tell Postgres about that:

```sql
COPY my_table FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv, HEADER true)
```

Check the syntax in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had also tried without header before and somehow added it again. Nonetheless, this throws `psycopg.errors.FeatureNotSupported: COPY HEADER only available in CSV mode`.

Comment: And it does not work when I remove the header, either.

Comment: I forgot to specify the format, answer updated.